# Slow performance on batchUpdate Spring 4 + OpenJDK11 + MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, spring

On previous setup of Tomcat with JDK 7 + Spring 3.2 + MySQL Connector/J 5.1.34 + MySQL 5.7.25 up to 400 000 data were inserted in database with ease.
After migrating to OpenJDK 11 (class file compilation set to target 1.8) + Spring 4.3.20 + MySQL Connector/J 8.0.13 + MySQL 5.7.25 same process takes considerable time and even hangs tomcat.

Am I missing any point here? JDBC URL has no change i.e. except characterSetResults=Cp1252 & characterEncoding=Cp1252 added.

Comment: Spring is at 5.x; I'd wonder why you are using an old version.  It's impossible to tell without profiling data to figure out where the time is being spent.  No idea about indexes, the size of your rollback segment, transactional behavior, etc.

Comment: @duffymo all controllers are using MultiActionController. If I use the same code with JDK7 it works fine. The java code we've is set to target as JDK 8.

Comment: Don't care about JDK 7 anymore.  Production version is JDK 11.  You should start by forgetting about the working version and concentrate on figuring out what changed.